# Let $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ be strictly increasing then

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ be strictly increasing then

(a) f is continuous.

(b) If f is continuous then f is onto.

(c) If f is onto then f is continuous.

(d) None of the above

It should be injective I am sure, but right now no counter example is coming in my mind. could any one help me?

Comment: No counterexample to (a)?

Comment: Nor (b)?${}{}{}$

Comment: You are correct that the function is injective.  There are linear or piecewise-linear counterexamples to parts (a), (b), and (c).  I'll post them in a bit if you haven't thought of them.

Comment: You can only be sure $f$ is continuous if it is bijective.

Comment: Try drawing a picture. This will answer (a), (b). For (c), try drawing a function that is onto but not continuous. Can you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monotonic functions can only have jump discontinuities.  If $f$ is onto and monotonic, we cannot have jump discontinuities, so it must be continuous.  There are counterexamples to the others.